# can anyone explain this wierd bahvor of python3?

Tags: python

I get this output

```
0
(1, 5)
(1, 5)
```

if punkt1[0] returns a like expected a number, why I get for the other print a weird kind of array back?

```
class Maths():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
  
    def abstand_punkt_punkt(self,punkt1,punkt2):
        print(int((punkt1[0])-(punkt2[0])))
        print(punkt1[0])
        print(punkt2[0])
        n=(((punkt1[0]-punkt2[0])**2)+((punkt1[1]-punkt2[1])**2))**0,5
        print(n)
        return n
m=Maths()
print(m.abstand_punkt_punkt([1,10],[1,100])
```

Comment: not sure i understand completely, but maybe it's because you have a trailing `,5` in the last expression? that should turn the result into a tuple in this case.

Comment: Actually, that is not the output this code will produce... Anyway what do you expect?

Comment: What steps have you taken to debug your own code? SO is a _terrible_ debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I followed each line on your code and came to the conculsion that it does what it is supposed to do.

`print(int((punkt1[0])-(punkt2[0])))` -> 1-1 = 0 -> prints 0 as an output.

`print(punkt1[0])` -> prints 1 (declared [1,10] for punkt1 so punkt1[0] is 1).

`print(punkt2[0])` ->prints 1 (declared [1,100] for punkt2 so punkt2[0] is 1).

`n=(((punkt1[0]-punkt2[0])**2)+((punkt1[1]-punkt2[1])**2))**0,5`:

`((punkt1[0]-punkt2[0])**2)` -> (1-1)**2 = 0

`((punkt1[1]-punkt2[1])**2))` -> (10-100)**2 = 8100 so by using "+" between them we get:
(0+8100)**0,5

if you can see: you power the sum of 0 and 8100 by 0 and you get 1,
after the 0 you wrote ",", so you'll get after the math functions -> n = 1,5.

if you declare a variable like so n = number,number , it creates a tuple.

Example:

```
new = 5,2
print(type(new))
```

Output:

```
<class 'tuple'>
```

so this is why you get (1,5) as an output.

I hope it was helpfull.